# R char sorting according Windows-1252 on linux

Tags: r, sorting, locale, collate

**Question:**

I need to sort a vector of character strings on my linux (ubuntu) machine in the same way as it is sorted on another windows machine with Windows-1252 locale collate.

On windows it works like this:

```r
> order(c("A", "a", "0", "_", "/"))
[1] 5 4 3 2 1
```

On ubuntu 20.4 it works like this:

```r
> order(c("A", "a", "0", "_", "/"))
[1] 4 5 3 2 1
```

**Further info:**
The locale on the windows machine is as follows:

```r
> Sys.getlocale()
[1] "LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252;LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252;LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=English_United States.1252"
```

What I've already try is to set the locale to en_US.CP1252 on the linux machine, but with no change in the sorting:

```r
> Sys.getlocale()
[1] "LC_CTYPE=en_US.CP1252;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=en_US.CP1252;LC_COLLATE=en_US.CP1252;LC_MONETARY=en_US.CP1252;LC_MESSAGES=en_US.CP1252;LC_PAPER=en_US.CP1252;LC_NAME=C;LC_ADDRESS=C;LC_TELEPHONE=C;LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.CP1252;LC_IDENTIFICATION=C"
```

I've also tried to pass the desired collation to the str_order function, but with no luck:

```
> str_order(c("A", "a", "0", "_", "/"), locale = "en")
[1] 4 5 3 2 1
```

Is there any native way to enforce the collation when sorting? If not, how could I write my own sorter/comparator?
Thank you!